# Sheaf of Sections of Cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Fulton's intersection theory book at Chapter 4 makes the following claim: If $\mathcal{E}$ is a locally free sheaf (on $X$), and $E:=Spec(Sym(\mathcal{E}))$ a total space of some cone/bundle on $X$, then the sheaf of sections of $E$ is $\mathcal{E}^{\vee}$. However, I have trouble understanding why the claim is true, as Fulton does not make any remarks about it. Thinking this locally does not seem to help either, so there must be some global way to think about this. Can you help me on this?

Comment: isn't this the universal property of the symmetric algebra? CAlg_A(Sym_A M, A) = Hom_A(M,A) = M^\vee

Comment: Oh now I am embarassed. I never thought of these as $A$-morphisms. Now everything is crystal clear. Thanks.

Comment: great! (15char)